# Is there a way to trigger migration imports from the admin UI?

Tags: 8, migrations

I want to use module [WordPress Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/wordpress_migrate) to import content from WordPress into my new Drupal 8 website. I can use the module's button "+Add import from WordPress" appearing on page admin/structure/migrate to create a new import group from a WordPress XML file. That is working alright.

After I create that Migration group, I can enter its details page. It will then display all migrations I may run from Wordpress.

What I can't do through admin interface is actually running the import. It is said that the absolute best option for this is running the import script on Drush and I can do that on my Docker local environment by running:

```
drush mi --all
```

I could also specify the name of the import group I want to use, but this is not the point here.

My question is: although it is not recommended because a PHP script could timeout etc., is it possible to run the import from within UI? I will import ~ 200 posts from Wordpress, which is not a daunting task for the website and I don't see any risk for script timeout.

Anyway, I can't find a command button or link to trigger the import process from UI. Why do I want to do that? Because my website will be hosted on a shared host where I don't have access to Drush commands.

In case such an option isn't available, what would you say are my options here? Create a custom module that would run this import only once? Is this a simple task to take over?

Comment: Every Drush command is also just executing PHP code. You could simply provide a custom form with your own submit function mimicking or calling https://git.drupalcode.org/project/migrate_tools/blob/8.x-4.x/src/Commands/MigrateToolsCommands.php#L281-330.

Answer (score 1):

A general migration runner in the UI is not yet implemented - the issue to add this is at https://www.drupal.org/node/2470882.

Comment: Seems https://www.drupal.org/node/2470882 got fixed now.